# NSDictionary with specific property of plist

Tags: objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

I have a plist with key values.
Each key represent a language, let's say 'it' 'en' ....ecc

The value of each key is another key/value(=array) set. At startup I would like to create a dictionary by reading only a specific key. Let's say the locale of my iphone is 'it', then the init method would only parse it key, because the only way I found by now is to make a dictionary from the whole plist file and then another dictionary.

But I can imagine this can become quite cpu consuming if I add more language in the future.

thanks
Leonardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not localize the plist file, thus having multiple plists?

Comment: I did exactly what you said (but I forgot to mark as answered)